# where can i download the skydrive sdk API jar file

Tags: onedrive

Where can i download the skydrive sdk jar to use the classes listed in below link? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh846808.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from sources : https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android